# What is the meaning behind 5000萬「袋住先」and D7689!@#?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, meaning-in-context

On a poster referring to the umbrella protests in Hong Kong, there is a Chinese politician depicted in the way of the picture "the scream" by Edward Munch. Next to him is a humanoid banana with googles screaming "**D7689!@#**". Above him is another oval shaped yellow humanoid like creature with googles parachuting using an umbrella. The lower part of the poster is a black bar with the text: **5000萬「袋住先」**.

I only know that this is an allusion, that the humanoid creature with googles is a depiction of Jiang Zemin and that the number represents some Chinese sentence that remotely resembles its pronunciation.

[image]

Comment: Please upload the picture or leave a link to it.

Comment: 欲知英文解释请把＂HK$50 million＂输入最喜欢互联网搜索引擎。for English explanation please search web using ＂HK$50 million＂

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pronunciation of "D"-"7" is similar to a Cantonese foul phrase (something similar to  fxxking hard).

689 is a common way to refer to the current Chief Executive (CE) of Hong Kong, because he won the election in 2012 by having 689 electoral votes out of the 1200-person Election Committee.

"袋住先" is also a common Cantonese saying.  "袋" here means the action to put something in your pocket, as analogous to "acceptance".  "袋住先" is to accept something at the time being, with a implicit promise that something better will be offered later.

Hong Kong would probably be having an electoral reform to adopt universal suffrage in 2016 CE election according to the Basic Law (supplemented by elaborated explanations from the Standing Committee of the National People's Congress of China).  The HK Government is promoting its Beijing-blessed proposal and many famous people are telling the citizens to "袋住先".  (This is IMO somehow self-contradictory because the proposal is advertised as "universal suffrage" and the Basic Law does not mention any improvement beyond "universal suffrage".)

As for "5000萬", please refer to http://www.theage.com.au/business/world-business/hong-kong-chief-executive-cy-leung-faces-questions-over-secret-7m-payout-from-australian-firm-20141008-1134yv.html

Answer (score 1):

"袋住先",   in Cantonese, means "take whatever come to you".

It is clearly a dual, even in English.

1. Take the money first no matter how meager the value or future outcome or suffering.
2. A graft practice.

There is a chronology of the sarcasm.  First, the HK chief minister(CM) postpone the transition of HK proper general election with huge compromise, asking the resident to  "take whatever come to you"("袋住先").
Then a scandal broke-out, as the HK CM are found taking a rebate/graft payment/bribe or whatever that fit the circumstances of "take whatever(bribe) come to you".

Answer (score 0):

keep it in your pocket, means, take it / grab it